# Swing animation to different parts of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use a swing animation to `href` to certain parts of my page. However I am not sure what to put to refer to the correct `sections` of my HTML. I think the best thing to do would be to select the `href id` that my `a` tag is referring to. I am open to new approaches

jQuery:

```
$("li a").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        var mode = "swing";
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(/*HERE*/).offset().top
        }, 750, mode);
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul id="nav_pills" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a id="test" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- about -->
<section id="about">
  <div class="border">
    ABOUT
  </div>
</section>

<!-- services -->
<section id="services">
  <div class="border">
    SERVICES
  </div>
</section>

<!-- portfolio -->
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="border">
    PORTFOLIO
  </div>
</section>

<!-- contact -->
<section id="contact">
  <div class="border">
    CONTACT
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/p0tavns5/2/

```
$("li a").each(function() { // $('a[href^="#"]') might be a safer selector
    $(this).on("click", function(e) {
        var mode = "swing";
        e.preventDefault(); //stop the default jump to fragment
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top // .hash is the element's href
        }, 750, mode);
    });
})
```

Source: http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery

This also has the advantage of graceful degradation. If it doesn't run (noscript or something), it will default to regular fragment linking.